# Filtering Values from Two Data Sets

Tags: tableau-api

I am very new to Tableau and am having trouble finding a way to filter between two data sets. These sets are Tableau Data Extracts so I am unable to create custom SQL to achieve this.

In DataSet1 I have levels of precipitation by date.

In DataSet2 I have sales revenue per date and store location.

I am trying to visualize the sum of sales revenue per store location on only days with precipitation. I thought I would be able to simply create a filtered list of all dates in DataSet1 that saw precipitation then subsequently filter all dates in DataSet2 to = my filtered list.

Any thoughts on how I would go about this? I feel like it should be relatively simple, but being so unfamiliar with the software I am having trouble locating a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried blending the data?http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v6.1/public/online/en-us/i1002331.html#i1002331

Answer (score 1):

Please look into Data Blending for Tableau.It is an interesting feature in tableau to link multiple data sources into one sheet.It can get laggy at times so use it carefully.
Some Tutorial Links:
http://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/data-blending-0
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/relate-summarized-data-60

Also the screenshot below shows the option to edit relationships between data sources which is essentially Data Blending

[image]